# Two-samples Z-test alternative for small samples (categorical data)

Tags: bootstrap, small-sample, z-test

I am looking for alternatives to 2 samples Z-test (2 independent samples) for categorical variables.

I have two datasets (same indicators measured in 2020 and 2021) I need to understand whether difference in proportions between 2020 and 2021 is statistically significant. For this, for indicators where the sample size is sufficient, I use z-test for two proportions, and the question is how should I treat variables where the sample size requirement for z-test is not met.

What are possible approaches|tests that could be used in this situation?

Could bootstrapping be used here? If yes, what should the sequence of actions look like?

Comment: Z tests would usually compare means when population variance is known (either under an assumption of normality or as an asymptotic approximation; it may also arise as an asymptotic approximation in other situations). What are you trying to find out about these categorical variables? How does an analogy with a comparison of means arise? Is this not a situation in which the usual chi-squared test(s) could apply?

Comment: @Glen_b thank you for your comment! I have two datasets (same indicators measured in 2020 and 2021) I need to understand whether difference in proportions between 2020 and 2021 is statistically significant. For this, for indicators where the sample size is sufficient, I use z-test for two proportions, and the question is how should I treat variables where the sample size requirement for z-test is not met.

Comment: Then you had better make that explicit in your question -- but what sample size requirement do you think there is?

Comment: @Glen_b thank you! I've put it in the question text. The sample size requirement for Z-test is n(success)*p >=10, which is not true for some of my variables. For some of them, even n>=30 is not met. Thus, I am looking for some other solutions for this issue.

Comment: It sounds like you might not have enough data to be able to detect the kind of difference that would be of interest to you.

Comment: @Hanna What sample sizes and proportions do you have, approximately?

Comment: @Glen_b some of the variables have around 20 observations both for sample 1 and sample 2 and the proportions vary from 5% to 30% i think, for these variables in general

Comment: Can you explain more about these indicators? Mainly trying to understand whether a Binomial model is suitable or not.